# Como pasar un parámetro a una función en react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Estoy tratando de extraer un elemento del estado de mi componente, para lo cual tengo una función que recibe un id y en base a este id extaer el elemento, pero al momento de recibir el parámetro obtengo undefined.

Código del componente.

```
import {leerPost} from '../../actions/Posts';
export class DetallePost extends Component {
  static propTypes={
    Nota:PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    leerPost:PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const {match:{params:{id}}}=this.props;
    this.props.leerPost(parseInt(id));//aqui ejecuto la función y le paso el id como parámetro
    console.log(id);
  }
  render() {
    return (
     ...
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
  Nota: state.Post.Nota,
});
const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>({
  leerPost:()=>dispatch(leerPost()),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(DetallePost);
```

Aquí tengo la función para extraer el elemento

```
export const leerPost = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log(id);//Me imprime undefined
  const posts = getState();
  dispatch({
    type: LEER_POST,
    payload: posts.Post.Post.filter((p) => p.id === id),
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi error estaba cuando pasaba la función a las propiedades.

Tenia esto:

```
const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>({
  leerPost:()=>dispatch(leerPost()),
});
```

Tenia que agregar un parámetro a eso:

```
const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>({
  leerPost:(id)=>dispatch(leerPost(id)),
});
```